# python multiprocessing work with hazelcast

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, hazelcast

I have another problem that I can not solve(( I have a cluster on hazelcast, and I want to create a hazelcast client in each separate subprocess, which would extract bunches  of entries from hazelcast. But when I want to run 3 processes, the first one is launched, takes out all the objects from hazelcast and leaves nothing for 2 and 3. How to make it processes asynchronously retrieve objects from hazelcast?

```
#test py
import os
import logging

# pip install hazelcast-client-python
import hazelcast 
from Customer import Customer

from datetime import datetime

from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

print "starting..."

# basic logging setup to see client logs
logging.basicConfig()
# logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def queue_parse_new():

    config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()

    portable_factory = {Customer.CLASS_ID: Customer}
    config.serialization_config.add_portable_factory(Customer.FACTORY_ID, portable_factory)

    # Hazelcast.Address is the hostname or IP address, e.g. 'localhost:5701'
    config.network_config.addresses.append('192.168.200.245:5701')

    print "retrieving client"
    client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
    print "client is retrieved"

    queue = client.get_queue("customers").blocking()

    while not queue.is_empty():
        list_of_dto = []
        queue.drain_to(list_of_dto, 10000)
        for i in list_of_dto:
            print i.foo + ' ' + str(os.getpid())
    else:
        client.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    proc = Process(queue_parse())
    proc1 = Process(queue_parse_new())
    proc2 = Process(queue_parse())

    proc.start()
    proc1.start()
    proc2.start()
```

Comment: There is only one queue_parse_new() call, and other two have queue_parse(), is there a typo or something, can you validate it?

Comment: Asimarslan, hello, yes it is a typo all processes must work with queue_parse_new(). Tell me please if you know, how to organize the code so that the hazelcast clients can work asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your example and it works. I use integer instead of your Customer object.

```
import multiprocessing
import logging
import hazelcast
from multiprocessing import Process


def fill_data():
    config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
    config.network_config.addresses.append('127.0.0.1:5701')
    client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
    queue = client.get_queue("customers").blocking()
    lst = [i for i in range(0, 10000)]
    for i in range(0, 10):
        queue.add_all(lst)
    print "test data ready", queue.size()
    client.shutdown()


def queue_parse():
    config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
    config.network_config.addresses.append('127.0.0.1:5701')
    current_process = multiprocessing.current_process()
    client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
    queue = client.get_queue("customers").blocking()
    while not queue.is_empty():
        list_of_dto = []
        queue.drain_to(list_of_dto, 10000)
        print "drained batch with size:", len(list_of_dto), "from process:", current_process.name

    else:
        client.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "starting..."
    # basic logging setup to see client logs
    logging.basicConfig()
    # logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fill_data()

    proc1 = Process(target=queue_parse, name="process-1")
    proc2 = Process(target=queue_parse, name="process-2")
    proc3 = Process(target=queue_parse, name="process-3")

    proc1.start()
    proc2.start()
    proc3.start()
```

The most important change in the code is how you create the Process.

```
proc1 = Process(target=queue_parse, name="process-1")
```

I pass in the target without parentheses and a process name to use from log.